# Charge density of sea water

Tags: charge, water, physical-chemistry, density, electrochemistry

If sea water contains salt ions and some H+ and OH- ions, what are the charge density of a certain volume of sea water? And is there a way to calculate?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the number of negative ions equals the number of positive ions, the net charge density in any volume of sea water is zero.